# Analisar imagem de URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

Como posso fazer para ao invés de enviar uma analisar a local ele analisar uma imagem de um endereço remoto ou uma url. Pois se eu tento substituir o endereço:  C:\Users\madureira\Downloads\JRMJ.jpg por uma URL é apresentada a mensagem de erro:
'Não há suporte para o formato do caminho dado.'

Código:

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string imageFilePath = @"C:\Users\madureira\Downloads\JRMJ.jpg";
    Literal1.Text= ObterEmocoes(imageFilePath);
}


  public async Task<string> ObterEmocoes(string imageFilePath)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage respostaHttp;
        string json;

        byte[] byteData = GetImageAsByteArray(imageFilePath);

        string url = "https://brazilsouth.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect";

        string queryString = "returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=false" +
            "&returnFaceAttributes=age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses," +
            "emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise";

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "<<key>>");
        using (ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
        {
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            respostaHttp = await httpClient.PostAsync($"{url}?{queryString}", content);
            json = await respostaHttp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        return json;
    }

    static byte[] GetImageAsByteArray(string imageFilePath)
    {
        using (FileStream fileStream =
            new FileStream(imageFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
            return binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)fileStream.Length);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pelo que percebi está a utilizar os serviços do **Cognitive Services** da **Microsoft**, que parece não suportar imagens remotas. Porque não fazer o _download_ da imagem temporariamente, tratá-la e depois removê-la?

Comment: @madujr, conseguiu evoluir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o que você envia é um `byte[]` e deseja obtê-lo também de uma url externa, adicione essa funcionalidade ao método `GetImageAsByteArray()` ou crie um novo específico para isso.

```
static byte[] GetImageAsByteArrayFromUrl(string imageUrlPath)
{
    byte[] byteData = null;

    using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        var url = new Uri(imageUrlPath);
        byteData = client.DownloadData(url);
    }

    return byteData;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado deu certo!!!